# How to increase the size of CLOB data type?

Tags: java, sql, derby, clob

I have created CLOB data type in java embedded database(derby)

I have a office document which size is around 273 KB.

Extract the document:

```
XWPFWordExtractor ext = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
            str = ext.getText();
           Reader r=new StringReader(str);
```

Inserting the document content:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Sithik/.netbeans/7.1.1/derby/ques"); /* Note use' / 'and not' \'  The url above will be different in your system*/
           PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into APP.NEW(Q1) values(?)");
           stmt.setCharacterStream(1, r, str.length());
           stmt.executeUpdate();
```

there are no exceptions and the query has been executed successfully but the thing is,only 2 KB size of the content got inserted.

Could you please help me to resolve it?

Thanks,
Sithik

Comment: How are you determining what got inserted? What is the CREATE TABLE statement for your table? What is str.length() when you run your program? What version of Derby are you running? What version of Java? Can you provide a complete example program that demonstrates this behavior? The Derby unit test suite verifies the insertion of clobs up to 2 GB in length, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: It must be something in your program code, Derby can most definitely store more than 2KB in a CLOB column. But an "office document" is not a String - it's a binary file and for that you *have* to use a `BLOB` column and write the data using `setBinaryStream`. I wouldn't be surprised if your "office document" has some null character after 2kb

Comment: How are you determing what got inserted?

Comment: How are you determing what got inserted?  From the database,I ran the query "select * from table_name" and column field shows only first two pages got inserted.... Derby version : 10.9.1 ...Java 1.6 ... If I ran the following query in the database then it returns Error code 30000, SQL state 54002: A string constant starting with ''"Product Name: Advance programing system
Exam Code: HP2-K20
Ex&' is too long.

Comment: An "alter table" SQL command would probably be the way to go.